# How can I create a set of modals?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create multiple buttons and each button opens a different modal using the logic of the code below, or another similar way to achieve this.

I don't want to use any libraries or frameworks, just vanilla Javascript.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? If you need multiple buttons and modals, work with individual IDs to address the elements.

Comment: The code you have here is working. You could encapsulate the code in an object or function to make it reusable without hard-coding it to specific IDs, perhaps even use a [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) to make it even easier. Up to you though; there are plenty of tutorials (on other sites) and questions (on this site) on how to make those happen.

Comment: @user1438038 i have to do 12 modals on my website. 2 modals on 6 sections. i wanted a way to apply all of the modal logic without having to do it one by one with IDs.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i wanted to know how to do it in a way without having to hard-coding it, but i confess that im not there yet considering my current level of js. that is why im having a hard time to translate the code above into a system with multiple modals without being repetitive with the code.

Comment: @devv: Then include a generic modal that exists only once and replace its content dynamically when one of the twelve buttons is pressed. Pass the dialog's title, message and callback functions for buttons as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByName("modal");


 function openmodal(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
 }
function closemodal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal{
display:none;}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button  onclick="openmodal('myModal')"> Open Modal</button>

<button  onclick="openmodal('myModal2')"> Open Modal2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="closemodal('myModal')">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="closemodal('myModal2')">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal222</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There are no elements with a `name` attribute of `"modal"`, so `getElementsByName("modal")` will return nothing.